# Composing mail in iOS 7 : Assertion failure in -[MFComposeSubjectView layoutSublayersOfLayer:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am currently running in troubles with iOS7 and the `MFMailComposeViewController`. Sometimes (quite often but not always), I have the following crash when presenting the `MFMailComposeViewController`:

> ** * Assertion failure in -[MFComposeSubjectView layoutSublayersOfLayer:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2903.23/UIView.m:8540

Here is how I present the controller:

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController* mailVC = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        mailVC.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [mailVC setSubject:@"blablabla"]];
        [mailVC setMessageBody:@"blablabla" isHTML:NO]; 
        mailVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
        mailVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

        if(isIpad) {
            [sharedParentViewController presentViewController:mailVC animated:YES completion:nil];
        } else {
            [sharedNavigationViewController presentViewController:mailVC animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
    }
```

`sharedParentViewController` and `sharedNavigationViewController` are defined macros to access root view controller everywhere in the app.

I set up a breakpoint on all exceptions but unfortunately, it never breaks.

With iOS6 and iOS5, everything works fine, any idea of what I can try to fix this?

EDIT:

Here is the crash log:

```
Stack Trace

Auto Layout still required after executing -layoutSubviews. MFComposeSubjectView's implementation of -layoutSubviews needs to call super.

0   CoreFoundation                      0x3099ff4b &lt;redacted&gt; + 130
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3b1366af objc_exception_throw + 38
2   CoreFoundation                      0x3099fe25 &lt;redacted&gt; + 0
3   Foundation                          0x31347fe3 &lt;redacted&gt; + 90
4   UIKit                               0x33112e63 &lt;redacted&gt; + 538
5   QuartzCore                          0x32d99c6b &lt;redacted&gt; + 142
6   QuartzCore                          0x32d9547b &lt;redacted&gt; + 350
7   QuartzCore                          0x32d9530d &lt;redacted&gt; + 16
8   QuartzCore                          0x32d94d1f &lt;redacted&gt; + 230
9   QuartzCore                          0x32d94b2f &lt;redacted&gt; + 314
10  QuartzCore                          0x32d8e85d &lt;redacted&gt; + 56
11  CoreFoundation                      0x3096b1cd &lt;redacted&gt; + 20
12  CoreFoundation                      0x30968b71 &lt;redacted&gt; + 284
13  CoreFoundation                      0x30968eb3 &lt;redacted&gt; + 730
14  CoreFoundation                      0x308d3c27 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
15  CoreFoundation                      0x308d3a0b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
16  GraphicsServices                    0x355c7283 GSEventRunModal + 138
17  UIKit                               0x33177049 UIApplicationMain + 1136
18  teleobs                             0x00037921 main + 116
19  teleobs                             0x000378a8 start + 40
```

Comment: Are u using appearance selectors to set navigation bar colors ? if u do so, try not to use images to generate colors!

Comment: @ChamiraFernando No, I checked right now, UIAppearance selectors are not used at all.

Comment: or u change navigation controller colors using image ? i mean [uicolor colorWithPatternImage] ?

Comment: @ChamiraFernando I do not use any pattern image. The only customization performed on navigation controller is this one :  `self.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];`

Comment: its hard to say where it happens.. can u see the whole crash log ?

Comment: @ChamiraFernando I have edited my question to show the whole crash log I have.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42134/discussion-between-gl0ub1l-and-chamira-fernando)

Comment: @c0d3Junk13 no solution for the moment, I will get back to this during the day.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this issue because of:

1. Autolayouts is enabled (in Storyboard, etc)
2. There is `UIView` category (or more) with calls of `- (void)layoutSubviews`

Check all `UIView` categories (in your project) if it calls `- (void)layoutSubviews`, try to comment this call for testing. Or just turn off autolayouts

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you try to `initialize` the `MFMailComposeViewController` with `initWithNibName:bundle:` instead of `init`. Try it this way, and it should work.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mailComposer setSubject:emailTitle];
[mailComposer setMessageBody:message isHTML:NO];
```

If it is a problem with your `macros` you should better first try to call the `MFMailComposeViewController` the normal way

```
[self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];
```

without a switch and if it works you can look how to switch it.

Comment: A regular `init` calls `[self initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was I tried to `presentViewController:` when `UIActionSheet` still was presented. It has it's own window which overlays ours one. I've added a small delay, `0.1f` seconds, and called the presentation of `MFMailComposeViewController` in `dispatch_after` block. After that it started to work correctly.

Try to increase delay up to `0.3f` if `0.1f` doesn't work.

I assume we will have the same problem for `UIAlertView` and other classes which use those own windows for presentation.

This solution is not elegant so if somebody has a better decision I would be happy to know it.

Answer (score 0):

in class `MFComposeSubjectView`，you rewrite -`layoutSubviews` but not call [super layoutSubviews]